# Reflux: How to listen to a subset of actions using `listanables` or `this.listenToMany`?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flux, reactjs-flux, refluxjs

Imagine that you have a huge actions object and some components / stores just want to listen subset of it.

```js
var actions = Reflux.createActions({ /* lots of actions with children*/});
```

How to listen only for a `subset` of these action and not do manually one by one `this.listenTo()`? Easiest way?

Answer (score 1):

So you do it easy.

In store:

```js
// ...
var actions = Reflux.createActions({ /* lots of actions with children*/});
module.exports = Reflux.createStore({
     listenables: {subsetKey: actions.subsetKey},
     // ...
```

In component:

```js
// ...
var actions = Reflux.createActions({ /* lots of actions with children*/});
module.exports = React.createClass({
      mixins: [Reflux.ListenerMixin],
      componentDidMount() {
           this.listenToMany({subsetKey: actions.subsetKey});
      }
      // ...
```